# Webservice printing access denied

Tags: web-services, printing

I have a webservice that takes PrintersSetting  and a file from a users PC and prints them to the printer on our print server. PrintersSetting settings is being a set by the user   In Dev and Testing environment it works fine but in production I am getting an error "Access Denied". we have made sure that the "Everyone" has access to the printer and we set in app.config 

we even log on to the server with the user account Thewebservice and print directly to the printer and that works fine. But we stil get that error message.

Anyone encounter this problem before?

Thanks,
Marios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the printing it was a call to a command line utility. the user was not admin on the box so there was insufficient rights to run the utility.